# Pjsua application made by pjsip register message error?

Tags: android, pjsip

I have built pjsua application for android from pjsip library by following the steps given in the pjsip website. The application working fine. When I try to register with sip server I am getting the following error. I have read that this error happens when the realm is not specified correct. I have tried with correct realm. still there is problem. Can anyone please help me?

```
05-15 12:35:55.231: I/apjsua(10693): 12:35:55.237 sip_auth_clien  ...Unable to set 
auth    for tdta0x5fb16678: can not find credential for 80.231.224.9/Digest
05-15 12:35:55.271: I/apjsua(10693): 12:35:55.279    pjsua_acc.c  ....SIP   
registration      
error: No suitable credential (PJSIP_ENOCREDENTIAL) [status=171101]
```

Comment: can you help me compile pjsip for android ?

Comment: https://github.com/alexbbb/pjsip-android-builder